# Can I manage same version for all the sub-package in lerna monorepo?

Tags: angular, version-control, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

```
my-lerna-repo/
package.json
packages/
    package-1/
        package.json
    package-2/
        package.json
            dependencies: {
                package-1
            }
```

I want to keep consistent version for for all the sub-packages. Also We have cross dependencies in sub-packages.

I want to achieve similar to how angular does.

https://github.com/angular/angular

They only manage package version at root level and in all sub-packages they mentioned 0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER. Build time it pick the version from root package.

Please let me know if there is any existing way to do this or I need to write my own custom script.

Comment: I did not find any solution for this so wrote custom script. While creating the deployable package we run that script before compilation. it iterate each and every package and replace 0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER version from parent package.json version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Lerna documentation if you want to publish all packages under the same version you need to use zero (0) as the major Lerna version in lenra.json file.

> Note: If you have a major version zero, all updates are considered breaking. Because of that, running lerna publish with a major version zero and choosing any non-prerelease version number will cause new versions to be published for all packages, even if not all packages have changed since the last release.

This is the mode that Babel is currently using. Use this if you want to automatically tie all package versions together. One issue with this approach is that a major change in any package will result in all packages having a new major version.

Example: "0" or "0.1.0"

```json
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "version": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) does with the [Fixed/Locked mode](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#fixedlocked-mode-default), which is the default for a Lerna project.

> Fixed mode Lerna projects operate on a single version line. The version is kept in the `lerna.json` file at the root of your project under the version key. When you run `lerna publish`, if a module has been updated since the last time a release was made, it will be updated to the new version you're releasing. This means that you only publish a new version of a package when you need to.

Comment: I don't think so [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) is using the same way i explained. Have you looked into [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular) repo? How it is using?

Comment: This only updates packages that have been modified. I think OP wants to always publish all packages at the same version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--force-publish` to make sure all of your packages are published under the same version.